How to split list of list by type
How can I split this list by Type so they separate type A from Type B?
List<List<TestData>> DatabaseList = new List<List<TestData>>();
List<TestData> DatabaseList1 = new List<TestData>();
List<TestData> DatabaseList2 = new List<TestData>();
List<TestData> DatabaseList3 = new List<TestData>();



DatabaseList1.Add(new TestData { Balance = 10, Name = "Data1 1", Type = "A" });
DatabaseList1.Add(new TestData { Balance = 20, Name = "Data1 2", Type = "A" });
DatabaseList1.Add(new TestData { Balance = 30, Name = "Data1 3", Type = "B" });

DatabaseList2.Add(new TestData { Balance = 100, Name = "Data2 1", Type = "A" });
DatabaseList2.Add(new TestData { Balance = 200, Name = "Data2 2", Type = "A" });
DatabaseList2.Add(new TestData { Balance = 300, Name = "Data2 3", Type = "B" });

DatabaseList3.Add(new TestData { Balance = 1000, Name = "Data3 1", Type = "A" });
DatabaseList3.Add(new TestData { Balance = 2000, Name = "Data3 2", Type = "A" });
DatabaseList3.Add(new TestData { Balance = 3000, Name = "Data3 3", Type = "B" });

DatabaseList.Add(DatabaseList1);
DatabaseList.Add(DatabaseList2);
DatabaseList.Add(DatabaseList3);

EDITs: I tried this:
var dat1 = DatabaseList.Select(a => a.Where(c=>c.Type == "A")).ToList();
var dat2 = DatabaseList.Select(a => a.Where(c=>c.Type == "B")).ToList();

But it is two separate lists could it be in : List<List<List>> SplitList = new List<List<List>>();

What is the desired result, please? What collection(s) should we have as a result?

@DmitryBychenko List<List<List>> SplitList = new List<List<List>>();

Where does the data come from? Database queries don't return nested lists. Is this data loaded from separate databases or tables? In that case you have two partitioning criteria, the Type and Database/Table, even if by "database" you mean the index in DatabaseList

@PanagiotisKanavos I agree the query is causing the complexity, multiple calls :(

@Dev it is two separate lists - would the Enumerable.Concat Method be of use?

It depends on what are you going to have. We can, say, filter out, unwanted types while keeping DatabaseList structure:
var DatabaseListA = DatabaseList
  .Select(list => list.Where(item => item.Type == "A").ToList())
  .ToList();

var DatabaseListB = DatabaseList
  .Select(list => list.Where(item => item.Type == "B").ToList())
  .ToList();

If you want some kind of grouping, we can first get all Types
var allTypes = DatabaseList
  .SelectMany(list => list.Select(item => item.Type))
  .Distinct(tp => tp);

and then repeat the code above, so you can try something like this:
var result = DatabaseList
  .SelectMany(list => list.Select(item => item.Type))
  .Distinct(tp => tp) 
  .OrderBy(tp => tp)
  .Select(tp => DatabaseList
     .Select(list => list.Where(item => item.Type == tp).ToList())
     .ToList())
  .ToList(); 


It's not clear what result you want but here are two possible solutions:
A. Sub-sub-lists: List<List<List<TestData>
// Each sublist in split into two sublists 
List<List<List<TestData>>> l = new ()
{
    DatabaseList.Select(a => a.Where(c=>c.Type == "A").ToList()).ToList(),
    DatabaseList.Select(a => a.Where(c=>c.Type == "B").ToList()).ToList()
};

// Or

List<List<List<TestData>>> l2 = DatabaseList
      .Select(sublist => sublist
                .GroupBy(keySelector: t => t.Type) // Group by type
                .Select(group => group.ToList()) // Discard the key and make all elements that have that key a list
              .ToList()) 
      .ToList();

This would give you:
sublist 0:
        subsubsublist 0:
                TestData { Balance = 10, Name = Data1 1, Type = A }
                TestData { Balance = 20, Name = Data1 2, Type = A }
        subsubsublist 2:
                TestData { Balance = 30, Name = Data1 3, Type = B }
sublist 1:
        subsubsublist 0:
                TestData { Balance = 100, Name = Data2 1, Type = A }
                TestData { Balance = 200, Name = Data2 2, Type = A }
        subsubsublist 2:
                TestData { Balance = 300, Name = Data2 3, Type = B }
sublist 2:
        subsubsublist 0:
                TestData { Balance = 1000, Name = Data3 1, Type = A }
                TestData { Balance = 2000, Name = Data3 2, Type = A }
        subsubsublist 2:
                TestData { Balance = 3000, Name = Data3 3, Type = B }

B. Just sub-lists: List<List<TestData>
It's also possible you want this:
// One list with "A" and onther list with "B"
List<List<TestData>> l = new ()
{
    // All elements with "A" from all sublists
    DatabaseList.SelectMany(a => a.Where(c=>c.Type == "A").ToList()).ToList(), 
    // All elements with "B" from all sublists
    DatabaseList.SelectMany(a => a.Where(c=>c.Type == "B").ToList()).ToList()
};

// This would achieve the same:
List<List<TestData>> l2 = DatabaseList
      .SelectMany(l => l) // This will make single list, without sublists;
      .GroupBy(keySelector: l => l.Type) // Group by type
      .Select(l => l.ToList()) // Discard the key and make all elements that have that key a List
      .ToList();

This way gives you:
tmaj@myhost:~/dev/games9$ dotnet run
sublist 0:
                TestData { Balance = 10, Name = Data1 1, Type = A }
                TestData { Balance = 20, Name = Data1 2, Type = A }
                TestData { Balance = 100, Name = Data2 1, Type = A }
                TestData { Balance = 200, Name = Data2 2, Type = A }
                TestData { Balance = 1000, Name = Data3 1, Type = A }
                TestData { Balance = 2000, Name = Data3 2, Type = A }
sublist 1:
                TestData { Balance = 30, Name = Data1 3, Type = B }
                TestData { Balance = 300, Name = Data2 3, Type = B }
                TestData { Balance = 3000, Name = Data3 3, Type = B }

